# Xcode iOS simulator content size not scalable

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, screen-resolution

I am an absolute beginner in iOS development and Xcode. I created single view project and set the size of the view controller to an iPhone 5.5inch screen. This can be seen here:

[image]

But if I run this with the simulator, I cannot see the whole content in my simulator screen:

[image]

Even when I use cmd+2/3/... to scale the window size, this doesn't help, because the content size is also scaled to the chosen setting.

How can I fix this?

Comment: r us using size classes?

Comment: You need to setup autolayout constraints so your views resize to fit on smaller screens.  The iPhone 5s simulator isn't a 5.5 inch screen so the layout you setup in the storyboard for a 5.5 inch screen isn't going to fit on it unless you add constraints so that your views resize.

Comment: I understand. I just reached now the constraint chapter in my tutorial. I have to set constraints like described in the answers above. Thank you! But why is then the option for the size given (on the right hand side of the first screen)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is set up AutoLayout constraints. Right now you have set up UI but it's not scalable to different screen sizes and that's why you don't see whole content. AutoLayout will scale that for you. Because AutoLayout is wide topic, I will show you the simplest way to do that.
All you have to do is select Add Missing Constraints(screenshot) and you are good to go.
[image]

Here is result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But what if I remove a button or another element? I clicked on the "Clear constraints" field, and indeed something clearing happened, but the result seems a bit fuzzy... What is the typic process when I remove an element?

Comment: You have several things to choose from actually. If you change position of element, then you should use  Update Constraints. If you remove element you should use Reset to Suggested Constraints. Clear Constraints is actually removing them so if you choose Clear Constraints, you should then again select Add Missing Constraints

Answer (score 1):

Select your storyboard in navigation, so it shows up in your editor. Now select the Assistant Editor view (the two rings icon), and in the right hand side of the editor click Manual, then select Preview.

Now you have a live preview on the right hand side so you can see what you're doing. You can add more device screen sizes here if you like.

In your storyboard, select Resolve Auto Layout Issues in the lower right corner. You need to snap the UIView elements to the blue helper-lines, and set constraints.

Apple has a nice tutorial here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your content does not scale properly.
If you see no green zoom button, then the window shows the whole content.
If you press Command-H for Home you should see the full iOS UI.

Comment: This does not even remotely answer the question.